Microsoft Teams Bot installation via a button on my website with query params to configure the app
I'm create a bot application for microsoft teams. I have provided a button on my website on the browser which has url https://teams.microsoft.com/l/app/?configDataId="id-2"(deeplink) which take the user to the teams app install dialog.
Now, how do I read the value of configDataId after the app is installed in the onTeamsMembersAddedEvent in the bot?
I have tried going through the turnContext that is provided by the bot and checking if somehow query params are being passed. Went through the documentation but there is nothing about this mentioned.

I don't think what you're trying to do is possible - I don't think you can even pass a parameter like this to your app (Teams wouldn't pass it on), and certainly it wouldn't come through to a bot context

Thought so. According to the documentation we can pass somed in query params for tab's deep links. But didn't find anything for my use case. Will try handle this with the bot configuration. Thanks @HiltonGiesenow

yes, but that's (a) for tabs only and (b) it's for a different scenario, not for your installation needs unfortunately. Most likely you were looking at a "Deep Link" scenario?
